# How can I crop binary images which dont have data like pics (matlab)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, binary

I have some Binary images which I want to remove the unusefull area an just keep the areas which have data like this example:

input image:

http://s1.upload7.ir/downloads/UsenferJ3Nb964UkpfABPC8YAyKPwAmh/1.bmp

output image:

http://s1.upload7.ir/downloads/TQHGaGCWCofspM2AEK3myfETc9ZwAMbm/2.bmp

I need the matlab code to this, any code and idea will be welcome.thanks

here is my code which got errore:

```
  clear all;close all;clc;
  I=imread('I111 p.bmp');
  figure,imshow(I),title('I')
  I=~I;
  [row,col]=size(I);

  Ix=I;

  % [x]=find(0);

  for i=1:row
      for j=1:col

         if I(i,j)==0
             Ix(i,:)=[];

      end
  end
  end
   figure,imshow(~Ix),title('Ix')
```

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro I use 2 **for** and one **if**  to detect black pixels but that was not correct. I don't have any idea to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simple code is below. Basically, you want to eliminate all rows and columns on the edge of the image that contain only 1's, since black is 0 and white is 1.

```
im = imread('1.bmp'); % insert actual path to image here
any_zeros = any(im==0, 1); % checks every column to see if any elements in column are zero
column_start = find(any_zeros==1, 1); % first column that contains 0
column_end = find(any_zeros==1, 1, 'last'); % last column that contains 0

any_zeros = any(im==0, 2); % checks every row to see if any elements in row are zero
row_start = find(any_zeros==1, 1); % first row that contains 0
row_end = find(any_zeros==1, 1, 'last'); % last row that contains 0

% final image has excess "white" on edges eliminated
final_im = im(row_start:row_end, column_start:column_end);
```

Comment: Much better answer than mine (a lot better explained) go for this.

Comment: @It's Magic , thanks you for your good answer. I do appreciate you for what you have done for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the load the image, convert to black and white and compare the whole matrix to 0 using the matrix operator, then sum in either direction to find the first and last index in either direction (using find) that is true.

Crop the image to those dimensions and save.

Comment: thanks for your response dear @user could u plz write the **find()** part down matlab code for me?

Comment: find(sum(Im==0,1)>0,1,'first')

Comment: I do appreciate you too for what you have done for me. thanks alot.